# Is there a way to listen for aspect ratio change in the dji sdk?

Tags: dji-sdk

Is there a way to listen for change of image size/aspect ratio in the dji-sdk for objective c either through a delegate or an event listener?

My scenario is that when the aspect ratio is changed, either through the DUXCameraSettingsController or through a secondary remote controller running the dji go app, I can not find adapt to the current viewport of the videofeed.

I am using DJI-SDK-iOS 4.6.1, DJI-UXSDK-iOS 4.6.0 and a Mavic Pro drone.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple different ways you can go about listening to the aspect ratio changed event.  The first approach using purely the SDK would be to do the following:

1.) We create the key we want to listen to.

`DJIFlightControllerKey *aspectRatioKey = [DJICameraKey keyWithParam:DJICameraParamPhotoAspectRatio];`

2.) From there we register a listener on the key like this:

```
[[DJISDKManager keyManager] startListeningForChangesOnKey: aspectRatioKey withListener:self andUpdateBlock:^(DJIKeyedValue * _Nullable oldValue, DJIKeyedValue * _Nullable newValue) { }];
```

3.) You can get the new aspect ratio in the update block by using:`(DJICameraPhotoAspectRatio)newValue.unsignedIntegerValue`

One thing to note about this approach is that it will not return the current value of the aspectRatio until it updates so you would need to do a getValueForKey right before this if you need the current value.

The second way uses a protocol declared in UXSDK `DUXObjectProtocol`and will also return the current value of the key immediately as well as when the key updates.

1.) Have the class you want to receive updates conform to the DUXObjectProtocol.

2.) In the implementation you now have to implement 2 methods:

`- (nonnull NSArray <__kindof DJIKey *> *)dependentKeys`

`- (void)transformValue:(nonnull DUXSDKModelValue *)value forKey:(nonnull __kindof DJIKey *)key;`

3.) Inside of dependedKeys you return an array of any keys you want to get updates on, so you could return:

`return @[[DJICameraKey keyWithParam:DJICameraParamPhotoAspectRatio]];`

4.) Inside of the transformValue:ForKey: you can get the value of the aspectRatio when it updates like so:

```
if ([key.param isEqualToString: DJICameraParamPhotoAspectRatio]) {
    self.aspectRatio = (DJICameraPhotoAspectRatio)[value unsignedIntegerValue];
}
```

5.) Optionally you can also implement the `- (void)update` method.  This method will be called after transform value is called so inside of here you can write your logic to update your user interface or whatever.

6.) The last thing to do is inside your initializer of your class that conforms to the DUXObjectProtocol you need to call:

`[[DUXSDKModel defaultSDKModel] registerDependentKeys:[self dependentKeys] forObject:self];`

and inside of dealloc call:

```
[[DUXSDKModel defaultSDKModel] unregisterDependentKeysForObject:self];
```

Let me know if this helps!